# Name of the spinning load/wait/buffer animation

Tags: animation, loading-animation

You see these things everywhere in both desktop and web development. Do they have a proper term or name? I thought I heard someone call it a "thumper" once, but Google doesn't seem to agree.

[image]

[image]

---

Not really sure how to categorize this, since it's applicable everywhere.

Comment: I use the word "spinner" to refer to these animations, though I don't know if that's the best name. For example, spinner in Android is a control similar to a combo box.

Comment: I've called them various things as well. I was wondering if they have a more official or specific name.

Comment: I guess there isn't a settled name...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The term you heard was most likely [Throbber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throbber) - this is from early web browsers (Mosaic, Netscape) where the page load indicator was indicated by animating the browser logo.

[image: NCSA Mosaic throbber]
[image: Netscape Navigator throbber]

Answer (score 8):

In Android development they're called "[indeterminate progress bars](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)."

In iOS development they're called "[activity indicators](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html)."

Another common term is "spinner", e.g., `STYLE_SPINNER` in [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html), but care should be taken to avoid confusion with [spinner-style menus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html).

Answer (score 1):

The term Sorrento for the buffering pinner, is from the "Meaning of Liff" series, the joke etymology book written by Douglas Adams & John Lloyd,

Comment: Can you add a source?

Comment: Sorrento n.
The thing that goes round and round as a YouTube video loads.

Answer (score -4):

It's called a sorrento, and was given a name by a former Manager of Google Milan in honour of his hometown.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this, Ben? I can't see anything on Google to verify it...